# RegexKitLite How to convert a PHP regex Expression in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I used this regex expression to search for img src in a string in one on my site.
Now I wan't to use this expression to do the same thing in objective c. How can I do that using RegexKitLite?
This is my expression

```
/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i
```

@Tim Pietzcker

Your code works great but for example if I try to search img in this string

```
<p><a href="http://www.nationalgeographic.it/popoli-culture/2011/08/03/news/per_la_tomba_del_boia-443612/?rssimage"> <img src="http://www.nationalgeographic.it/images/2011/07/29/115624013-20034abf-4d91-40fe-98ab-782f06a9854d.jpg" width="140" align="left" hspace="10"></a>Scoperta in America del Sud la sepoltura pre-incaica di un uomo circondato da coltelli cerimoniali che secondo gli archeologi eseguiva sacrifici umani</p>
```

I have this result in my array:

```
matchArray: (
    "<img src=\"http://www.nationalgeographic.it/images/2011/07/29/115624013-20034abf-4d91-40fe-98ab-782f06a9854d.jpg\" width=\"140\" align=\"left\" hspace=\"10\">"
)
```

How can I mod your regex to only get the content of src tag? thank you so much

Comment: I am pretty sure that apple are not accepting application that use RegexKitLite any more because it used a private library (libicu), you are supposed to use NSRegularExpression now, which uses the same libicu library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` delimiters are throwing you off. Also, you should at least use lazy quantifiers. Try this:

```
NSString *regexString = @"(?i)<img.+?src=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"].*?>";
```

This breaks when filenames contain quotes, by the way. Could that be a problem for you?

A regex that's a bit safer (and that handles quotes well) would be

```
NSString *regexString = @"(?i)<img[^<>]+?src=(['\"])((?:(?!\\1).)+)\\1[^<>]*>";
```

However, now the matches filename will be in capture group 2, not 1, so you need to modify any code that uses the filename after the match.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works but I only wan't the content of the src= tag! I added some info at my question! look

Comment: You need to access the second capturing group. I think you get this using the `capture:2L` parameter. Check page 14 in the [RegexKitLite manual](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/regexkit/RegexKitLite/RegexKitLite-4.0/RegexKitLite-4.0.pdf).